# Google speech to text api is partially converting .flac file into text

Tags: ffmpeg, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

Steps followed:

1. Converted .mp3 to .flac using ffmpeg.
2. Ran this command 
   `gs://xxx/xxx.flac --language-code=en-US --async --encoding=FLAC --sample-rate=44100`.
3. After processing it, is showing result in JSON format, but its not relevant to audio file.

JSON result looks like:

```
{
  "@type": "xxx",
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.71890223,
          "transcript": "I reports everybody."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.5876879,
          "transcript": "dear, it's your"
        }
      ]
    }
......
}]}
```

Can please someone help me in figuring out why it is not converting the audio files correctly? Am I missing any tags?.

Comment: Did you post the whole command? Checking the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-gcloud) I can see the following example for less than 60 seconds audio files: `gcloud ml speech recognize 'gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac' --language-code='en-US' --async`

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, using ffmpeg. When I use soundconverter, everything is fine. The optimal parameters for ffmpeg that I've found were:
-compression_level 0 -lpc_type none -ac 1 -ar 48k  -min_partition_order 4 -max_partition_order 4, but it is still better with soundconverter

Comment: I've found another way using ffmpeg - first convert mp3 to wave:
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 48000 -ac 1 file.wav
then convert wave to flac:
ffmpeg -i file.wav file.flac
The transcription from google service now is better than the other tries

Comment: Thanks @Max, will try this